# print a data in dd dt tags in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I have a data in angular JS something like this  :

**controller.js**

```
 someControllers.controller('viewDetail',function($scope){
       $scope.list = [{
          "id":"1",
          "first_name":"Super",
          "last_name":"Admin",
          "email":"superadmin@123.com",
          "status":"1",
          "is_superadmin":"1"
       }];
    });
```

Now i want to Print this data into my view in this way

**view.html**

```
<dl>
   <dt>id</dt>
   <dd>1</dd>
   <dt>first_name</dt>
   <dd>super</dd>
   <dt>last_name</dt>
   <dd>Admin</dd>
   <dt>email</dt>
   <dd>superadmin@123.com</dd>
</dl>
```

and so on ...

please tell me how i can do this. ng-repeat does not work for me.

**Note :**
The contents of the json object may be dynamic.

Comment: Where is ng-repeat in your view? Why are you overwriting the $scope object with an array?

Answer (score 0):

**First, You need to assign the JSON to object, not the $scope directly**

```
someControllers.controller('viewDetail',function($scope){
       $scope.list = [{
          "id":"1",
          "first_name":"Super",
          "last_name":"Admin",
          "email":"superadmin@123.com",
          "status":"1",
          "is_superadmin":"1"
       }];
    });
```

And use *`ng-repeat`* on that object.

```
<dl ng-repeat="item in list">
   <dt>id</dt>
   <dd>{{item.id}}</dd>
   <dt>first_name</dt>
   <dd>{{item.first_name}}</dd>
   <dt>last_name</dt>
   <dd>{{item.last_name}}</dd>
   <dt>email</dt>
   <dd>{{item.email}}</dd>
</dl>
```

**UPDATE :**

If the JSON fields are unknown loop through each JSON object also.

```
<div class="boredered-box" ng-repeat="item in list">
      <dl ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">
         <dt>{{key}}</dt>
         <dd>{{value}}</dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
```

[Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gTpMnKEwB4l8O81Q037R?p=preview)

Comment: The contents of the j son object may be dynamic.

Comment: Do you mean the fields?

Comment: yes the fields are dynamic. It may be anything other than the ones listed above